# jquery progress bar dont get value from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to use ajax to get the value from a mysql table, to show that info on the progress bar, but it wont work

jquery:

```
  $(function() {
    $.get("index.php?page=check", function(data) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
          value: data
        });
    });
  });
```

i'm trying to get the progress bar to show the exp of a player, the check.php returns 50, the data val is 50, (alerted it) but the progress bar show nothing. why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say that the result you are returning is a string - but the progress bar plugin is expecting an integer.

Try passing the value as `parseInt( data )`.

```
$.get("index.php?page=check", function(data) {
    var progress_value = parseInt( data );
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
      value: progress_value
    });
});
```

Looking at the [progressbar's API](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/), the [`value` parameter](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#option-value) does expect a number (or a boolean):

> **value** - valueType: Number or Boolean (Default: 0)
>
> The value of the progressbar. 
>   Multiple types supported:
>   **Number**: A value between `0` and the `max`.
>   **Boolean**: Value can be set to `false` to create an indeterminate progressbar.

Comment: It all depends on what your server is returning... Take a look at `index.php?page=check` and see exactly what the return value is. If you make sure that you return a number, then you won't need that `parseInt()` function. Although it might not be a bad idea to leave it in as defensive programming (to prevent future errors).

Comment: i better leave it there, i'll make some errors in the future for sure, i'm kinda learning js, php, as i'm doing my website (web based game), yes it did

Comment: @user3052629 - cool. You might want to add a check in the PHP code also to make sure that you are always returning a number (even if it's `0`). Glad to help! Happy coding!

Comment: yes of course, i just made the basic php page to see if its working. thx again